# NextJS 14 app directory route.js testing fails with Vitest

Tags: next.js, vitest

How can be the route.js tested?

```js
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest'
import { POST } from './route'


describe('[POST] /api/test', () => {

  it('should respond with a `400` status code and error message', async () => {
    const request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/api/test', {
      method: 'POST'
    })
    const res = await POST(request)
    const body = await res.json()
    expect(res.status).toBe(400)
  })

})
```

it fails on `.json()` because it doesn't exists on the `Request` object

```js
export const POST = async (request: Request) => {
  const data = await request.json()
  ...
}
```

I'm using vitest with `jsdom` environment.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling the answer is to wrap `Request` with `NextRequest`

```js
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

const request = new NextRequest(
  new Request('http://localhost:3000/api/test', {
    method: 'POST'
  })
)
```

Hope it will help you too